# AngularJS ng-repeat binding error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am recieving the following error while trying to bind values with ng-repeat
TypeError: Cannot read property '#' of undefined

html:

```
<ul ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="people in peoples">
        {{people.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var PeopleCtrl = function ($scope) {
$scope.peoples [
    {name: 'Zed'},
    {name: 'Ben'}
];
};
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks

Comment: Are you registering the controller?

Comment: Put your code in jsFiddle or plunker and post the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your controller like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('PeopleCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.peoples = [
        {name: 'John'},
        {name: 'Jane'}
    ];
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eL3okv5w/ (Note the [Fiddle Options] in the left menu.)

And the follow is another example

http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/ (Note ng-app tag in html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem you have something like

```
$scope.peoples [
    {name: 'Zed'},
    {name: 'Ben'}
];
```

but it should looks like

```
$scope.peoples =  [
  {name: 'Zed'},
  {name: 'Ben'}
];
```

You are missing equal sign you need to assign the values to your variable in order to use it `=` is used to assign values to your variable